# How to fix "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected Token {" -- clockify extension

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-extension, clockify

Currently i'm trying to add features to an existing MantisHub integration for clockify using the Clockify API (https://clockify.me/developers-api). I added functions in "src/helpers/integration-helper.js" to manipulate clockify projects & workspaces. I want to reference these exported functions within "src/integrations/mantishub.js" however when I try the following:

```
import {ProjectExists, createWorkspaceProject} from "../helpers/integration-helper";
```

(where ProjectExists and createWorkspaceProjects are the exported functions I added.)

I get the following error in chrome:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected toke {
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong (i'm relatively new to js).

I've tried using dynamic imports instead as such:

```
var helper_path = '../helpers/integration-helper';

        import(helper_path)
            .then(module => {

                //check if project exists
                var projectExists = module.ProjectExists(project);

                //create the project if it doesn't
                if(projectExists)
                {
                    //create project
                    module.createWorkspaceProject(project);

                    link = clockifyButton.createButton(description, project);
                }
                else
                {
                    link = clockifyButton.createButton(description);
                }
            })
            .catch(err => {

                    //create the button as normal
                    link = clockifyButton.createButton(description);
            });
```

but instead get the following error:

```
Not allowed to load local resource
```

How can import/access functions from other modules within the mantishub.js integration?

Thank you!

Edit 9/13/2019 -

Here is the repository to the Clockify app:

https://github.com/clockify/browser-extension

Comment: Please mention the code inside `integration-helper` file

Comment: You can't use modules in content scripts **natively**, only if you compile the code using webpack or a similar tool into a standard single bundle. Same for **native** dynamic imports (not via webpack), with the additional restriction that `.js` extension must be specified.

Comment: @YasserMas I have provided a link to the repo for the Clockify app -- the native code (without my added functions) are in **/src/helpers/**. The functions I wrote are in the same vein as exported functions that exist in there already and even those I can't call.

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks -- I didn't know what content scripts were. How can I extend a content script then in a portable fashion without having to add a lot of overhead in the established compilation set up by Clockify in their original repo?

Comment: I can't say but that extension's readme says it should be compiled so I guess you should do it.

Comment: Please mention the current `helper` file with your functions, it seems that there is extra curly braces  `{` please validate the file if there is any syntax error